# closest distance between hull and box

Tags: geometry, collision-detection

What would be the best way to find the closest distance between a convex hull and an axis aligned box ? By closest distance I mean the pair of points on the hull and box that are closest to each other. We can assume that we know that we know that the hull and box do not intersect.

The hull is given by faces, vertices and I can triangulate the faces if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paper here gives an algorithm to find closest pair between two convex hulls. http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/pubs/SIGGRAPH04_Ericson_GJK_notes.pdf

For some time, I thought that may be one of the hulls being AABB would make this algorithm unnecessary. Unfortunately, I didn't find that to be true.

The idea behind this algorithm is that you take Minkowski difference of two hulls. The closest pair would be a point in this Minkowski difference closest to the origin. Cartheodory's theorem says that in a d dimensional space, you need only d+1 points to represent a point in the hull. So basically you choose d+1 sized sets of the minkowski difference and find their closest distance to the origin. The closest point to the origin is found through an iterative algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

For case of hull inside a box (or any other convex object):

If they don't intersect than the closest point in the hull would be a vertex of the hull, never middle of a face.

Simply iterating trough all vertices of the hull and computing distance to each side of the box will let you find pair of points (vertex of the hull + point on a face of the box). Note that is a face of the hull is parallel to one of the box's faces you'll get more than one pair at the same distance.

Hull outside the box:

Pair contains point of an edge of the hull or box and point on the second object. Iterating through all edges of the hull and box and compute distance to all faces of the other object looks like an approach, but better one should exist.

Comment: Don't think so. Imagine an AABB and another convex hull which is an oriented box which has a face closest to a corner of the box. In this case the closest pair is the corner of box and a point on face of the hull.

Comment: I think the closest pair would always have a a box vertex or a hull vertex. Then, one possible solution is to first iterate over the box vertices and find the closest distance to hull faces. Then iterate over hull vertices and find closest distance to box faces. Not sure if it misses a possibility.

Comment: Somehow I've considered only hull inside a box. You are right if the box  does not contain the hull one of the box's vertices could be in the pair. Only one point in pair have to be a vertex - imagine huge box with tiny hull next to middle of box's face. So yes your suggestion is more generic and look correct.

Comment: I'll take back my statement. Imagine a huge box and a tiny hull passes over an edge at an angle. The closest pair would be a point in the edge and a point on teh face of the hull.

Comment: I've updated the answer based on your comments, but it looks like time to get a book :)

Comment: This is probably it: http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/pubs/SIGGRAPH04_Ericson_GJK_notes.pdf

Comment: May be good idea to add your own answer with small summary of the things you've found and accept it.

Comment: Just did. Hope this is helpful to someone!